# Pandoc can't process .tex document due tikz required semicolon

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pdftex, pandoc

I've tried to convert an "article" (I'm still undergrad) from `tex` to `docx` extension.

Pandoc is giving me the following error each time I attempt to convert the file.

```
>pandoc meta.tex -o meta.docx

Error at "source" (line 40, column 1):
unexpected }
expecting \end{document}
};
^
```

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The original template (the Legrand Orange Book Template) can be found here --> http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book
% Original author of the Legrand Orange Book Template:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
% TEMPLATE EDITOR: Miguel Avila
% Original License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.8cm,right=2.8cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{format-color}{HTML}{0b6969}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   STRUCTURE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (current page.north west) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[format-color](-2.8cm,3cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}; % ERROR LINE, because the nested picture

\matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=10cm] at (current page.center) {
    \node [fill=black,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm] {
        \fontsize{56}{56}\centering\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth} {
            \centering \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Portair}}\\ % Book title
            \textcolor{white}{\huge \textbf{Man in the middle}}
        }
    };\\
    \node [inner sep=0.5cm,fill=black,text opacity=1,fill opacity=0.4] {
        \fontsize{28}{28}\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth} {
            \centering\textcolor{white}{\huge Miguel Avila}
        }
    }; % Author name
    \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This problem is repeated when I tried to use `tex4ht`

---Thank you beforehand---

Comment: Nesting tikzpictures is usually fraught with peril.  But it does seem like you end the inner tikzpicture but not the outer (nor the document).  Are you able to fix that?  For that matter, if you no longer nest the tikzpictures, do things work out better?

Comment: @Teepeemm I put outside the nested picture and it worked, pandoc produced the file. However, is there any other way to do this? I have many other nested pictures.

Comment: I cannot compile your sample even with pdflatex, it doesn't close `tikzpicture` and `document` environments. It also doesn't include TikZ package. I can compile your document to HTML with TeX4ht, using the [dvisvgm4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht) driver. It unfortunately doesn't work for the ODT output, because SVG images are not supported by ODT.

Comment: @michal.h21 I have updated the post so that there is a compilable version with the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can convert your document to HTML using TeX4ht and [alternative driver for TikZ to SVG conversion](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht).

The document just needs slight edit, in order to load the driver and to fix some mysterious error:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The original template (the Legrand Orange Book Template) can be found here --> http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book
% Original author of the Legrand Orange Book Template:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
% TEMPLATE EDITOR: Miguel Avila
% Original License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.8cm,right=2.8cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry} % Page margins
\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{format-color}{HTML}{0b6969}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\HCode
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\def\pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options{}
\fi
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   STRUCTURE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,ampersand replacement=\&]
\node (current page.north west) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[format-color](-2.8cm,3cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}; % ERROR LINE, because the nested picture

\matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=10cm] at (current page.center) {
    \node [fill=black,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm] {
        \fontsize{56}{56}\centering\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth} {
            \centering \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Portair}}\\ % Book title
            \textcolor{white}{\huge \textbf{Man in the middle}}
        }
    };\\
    \node [inner sep=0.5cm,fill=black,text opacity=1,fill opacity=0.4] {
        \fontsize{28}{28}\centering\bfseries\sffamily\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth} {
            \centering\textcolor{white}{\huge Miguel Avila}
        }
    }; % Author name
    \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The added code is this:

```
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\HCode
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\def\pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options{}
\fi
\makeatother
```

It changes the TikZ driver and defines a control sequence that TikZ complain that isn't defined.

Here is the produced HTML file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, now I'll just handle the positions of my nodes directly.